# Lookup if the first entry in a set of data matches a particular date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

I have a set of columns showing me how much a customer spent on a monthly basis.
Each month, a new column is added for the current month.
I also have a date selector in order to look at historical data.

I've made a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bHLxaeuVvp3EbTU1Gq9KSAtTZdSs2kVJpvTNuZCxO9Y/edit#gid=349128603) to make it easier to understand my problem.

I would need a formula with the following requirements:

- If a first purchase was done on the month shown with the date selector (in 'Dashboard'!B1), then the customer is considered new. For instance, for this month, if the first entry of a row is in column G, then the customer is new.
- The reference for the last column is dynamic, as each month, a new column will be added on the right.
- Customer ID is used as a reference for lookup formula.
- For rows 2 and 5, customers are never considered new, as we don't have visibility before August 2022.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added formula to your sheet:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(A4:A),IF(INT(B1)=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4:A,{Data!A2:A,BYROW(Data!B2:Z,LAMBDA(bx,IF(COUNTA(bx)=0,,IF(INDEX(bx,,1)<>"",,+FILTER(Data!B$1:Z$1,bx<>"")))))},2,)),"Yes","No"),))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply (and apologies for my late answer ...) It works perfectly.
Didn't think of using BYROW/LAMBDA to map my entire dataset.
Awesome, thanks again!